# OpenGL - reusing a texture id

Tags: opengl

I have a scenario where I need to change texture parameters and load a new data. Can I generate a texture id (`glGenTextures`) only once and then call for a user request the following code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img.internalformat, img.width, img.height, 0, img.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.buf);
```

Should I delete and generate a new texture id before calling subsequent glTexImage2D ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I develop a gui application which uses OpenGL. An user can load some image so I wonder if deleting and creating a new texture id each time make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If i understood your question correctly you can call `glDeleteTextures`, delete the texture and reuse the name. Here is more information:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml